# MIME types in .htaccess with or without leading dot

Tags: .htaccess, mime-types

I have some issues with playing mp4 in Firefox (no surprise there). Most of the time, it was suggested to add some MIME types in my .htaccess file. Something like:

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v
AddType audio/mp4 m4a
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType audio/ogg ogg oga
AddType video/webm webm
```

Some people suggested the same, but with a leading dot:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType audio/ogg .ogg .oga
AddType video/webm .webm
```

What’s the difference between these two snippets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The extension argument is case-insensitive and can be specified with or without a leading dot.

So in short it makes no difference, they will both achieve the same result. [**Read more about AddType here.**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)