# .txt file opened in IE should not render the html tags

Tags: html

I have a link in my html page, which opens a text file on a new window when I click on it. The text file which is opened has html code in it. Due to this, when I open the file, it is rendering the HTML code and printing the output in the text file. I need to avoid this and print the html tags alone instead of rendering HTML.

Is there any way I can get the html tags displayed instead of rendering the html output in the text file displayed using IE?

TIA.

Comment: When i open a .txt file in IE it doesn't render the html code. What IE version do you use?

Comment: Exactly. Use file-type *.txt to get the plain unredered content. IE would only render HTML-Files (html5 and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Check the MIME type. It should be text/plain for normal text; then IE won't render the HTML. If you can't find it or need to change it, the easiest way is in the .htaccess in the root of your server:

```
AddType text/plain txt
```

That adds the MIME type text/plain to the file extension txt.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to tell your server that your .txt file is a text plain file and so he will say to the browser to just print it and not render it like html.

This could be done by using .htaccess file in the same folder that your file is.

And adding a line like this one :
AddType text/plain .txt

[Here is a ressource that can help you](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/)

Comment: Your htaccess code will not work: the last argument in an AddType command should not be preceded by a period.

Comment: There is no difference you can add a period or not.
[See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485765/mime-types-in-htaccess-with-or-without-leading-dot)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.txt` it must open as plain text instead of html. Well here's another solution, if you just want to see the HTML code present in that `.txt` file (and you are using php):
Make a php file and type:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("path/to/file.txt");
echo htmlentities($file_contents);
```

This will basically give you the file contents with all the tags etc and escape the html characters.

Another solution will be to paste that `.txt` file in a new `.php` and change the header content-type to text/plain.
**EDIT**
I made a little snippet, you provide it the filename or path and it'll show you it's real content in the `.txt` format event if it is a `.html` file:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");

if ( isset($_GET['filename']) )
{
    if ( file_exists($_GET['filename'])):
        echo file_get_contents($_GET['filename']);
    endif;
}
```

For example if you wanna see test.txt file type `yourdomain.com/snippet.php?filename=test.txt`